# Triple integral over a sphere

Tags: integration

[image]

I did the first integral in a), but im not sure about b). K is the sphere x^2+y^2+z^2 ≤ 1. Why can I use symmetry in b)? The solution is (1/3) of the answer in a). I want to understand how the symmetry works out in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you can divide the integral in `a` into three parts and since you are integrating over a sphere of radius one centered at the origin then x, y, z have the same values and give you the same result.

So you can replace y and z with x so you got 3 times the integral in `b`.

Answer (score 0):

In general if your integrand $f(x,y,z)$ is such that $f(x,y,z)=f(-x,y,z)$ and the domain of integration is symmetric respect to the $yz$ plane you can split the integral as a sum.
In your case the sphere $K:=\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3 :x^2+y^2+z^2\le1\}$ is symmetric respect to the plane $yz$.
So, if we now consider the restriction $K^+:=\{(x,y,z)\in K:x>0\}$ and an even function $f$ (respect to the variable $x$) then we would  have
$$\iiint_Kf=2\iiint_{K^+}f$$ which can be easy solved using a change of variables.